# Create blockwise shifted sparse matrix in matlab directly

Tags: matlab, sparse-matrix

I struggle to create a sparse matrix efficiently in matlab.

The problem looks like this:

Let's take a square matrix

a = 4;
b = 2;

t = rand(a,a);

What I want is equivalent to
P = sparse(kron(eye(a),ones(1,b)).*repmat(t,1,b))

Only that will be a = 12*2^10 and b = 2^10 (i.e. first creating the element wise multiplication between the kroneker product and the repmat of t is too memory intensive).

I've been browsing around and couldn't find a related question. My idea is to implement this matrix directly using the sparse(B,d,m,n) or spidag() syntax.

Would be amazing if someone had an idea.

Cheers

I expect a matrix like this:

P = sparse(kron(eye(a),ones(1,b)).*repmat(t,1,b))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested with your example and `b=3`.

```
r = repelem(1:a,1,b)
c = mod( repmat(0:(b-1),1,a) + (r-1)*b, a ) + 1;
P = sparse( r, 1:a*b, t(sub2ind([a,a],r,c)) );
```

Logic:

- `r` is the row index, which is the same for the sparse output and row input from `t`; each row repeated `b` times.
- `c` is the column index within `t` to take the value from. This appears to start as `1:b`, and then take the next `b` elements starting from the following column, wrapping round to column 1.

Then you can directly form the sparse matrix extracting elements from `t` using a linear index from `r` and `c`.

Output:

```
>> P = sparse(kron(eye(a),ones(1,b)).*repmat(t,1,b))

P =

   (1,1)       0.8147
   (1,2)       0.6324
   (2,3)       0.9649
   (2,4)       0.4854
   (3,5)       0.1270
   (3,6)       0.2785
   (4,7)       0.9706
   (4,8)       0.1419

>> s = sparse( r, 1:a*b, t(sub2ind([a,a],r,c)) )

s =

   (1,1)       0.8147
   (1,2)       0.6324
   (2,3)       0.9649
   (2,4)       0.4854
   (3,5)       0.1270
   (3,6)       0.2785
   (4,7)       0.9706
   (4,8)       0.1419
```

Comment: I was typing more or less the same answer, just longer and without `sub2ind` :-)

Comment: It's a miracle, I beat @Luis to an answer which involves some indexing manipulation

Comment: Next time I'll post the answer and _then_ write the explanation :-P